# Solve the matrix equation $[I+X(I-ST)^{-1}S](I-TS) = I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $I, S, T$ and $X$ are linear transformations of the vector space $W$, that $I$ is the identity and that $I-ST$ is invertible. Solve the equation
$$[I+X(I-ST)^{-1}S](I-TS) = I$$
for $X$ and express the inverse of $(I-TS)$ in terms of $I, S, T$ and $(I-ST)^{-1}$.

I can figure out that $XS=TS$ but I don't know how to get rid of $S$.