# Let $A, B : V \to V$ be linear transformations, where V is a vector space. Prove that $I - ST$ is invertible iff $I - TS$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inverse

It's very similar to [Solve the matrix equation $[I+X(I-ST)^{-1}S](I-TS) = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842710/solve-the-matrix-equation-ixi-st-1si-ts-i), but there's no answer given to that one.

A hint given is to consider $$I + T(I - ST)^{-1}S.$$ I tried to expand it, but things didn't cancel .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that if $I-ST$ is invertible, then the expression you are given to "consider" is actually a candidate for the inverse of $I-TS$, since:
$$
(I - TS)(I + T(I-ST)^{-1}S) = I - TS  + T(I-ST)^{-1}S - TST(I-ST)^{-1}S \\
 = I - T\bigg(I - (I-ST)^{-1} + ST(I-ST)^{-1}\bigg)S  \\
= I - T(I + (-I+ST)(I-ST)^{-1})S 
 = I - T0S = I$$

which shows that $I-TS$ is invertible, and furthermore we have a formula for the inverse.

The converse is very similar : just switch $S$ and $T$ in the derivation above.

Answer (score 2):

If $ I-ST $ is not invertible,  let $ v $ be non-zero such that $ STv=v $. Then $ TS-I $ vanishes on the non-zero vector $ Tv $.

Comment: How do you justify the existence of such a $v$? And what do you mean it vanishes? I think it means becomes 0, but then $(TS-I) (Tv) = T(ST)v - Tv = 0 -Tv = -Tv$, which is non-zero

Comment: Since $I-ST$ is not invertible, there exists some $v\in V$ such that $v\neq 0$ and $(I-ST)(v)=0$ (Ker$I-ST\neq \{0\})$, apply linearity and we get $Iv-STv=0 \Rightarrow v=STv$. Then we have $(TS-I)(Tv)=TS(Tv)-ITv=T(STv)-Tv=Tv-Tv=0$

Comment: @Saad being non-invertible is equivalent to having a non-trivial kernel.  As for the meaning of "vanishes", you are correct,  but your subsequent computation is wrong: by construction $ TSTv $ is $ Tv $, not $0 $.